# show more direction from each 2 marker javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've already show route directions from 2 marker, marker 1 contain lat & lng, marker 2 contain lat2 & lng2. From that markers , maps will show route direction from marker 1 and marker 2, and my problem is there are many couple of markers and I want to show all route direction from each couple of marker so the result is many route directions will show on map. Help me with this

Check my code below

(I've added full code of this project from beginning)

```
// DIRECTION
function initMap() {

var ren, ser;
var marker, marker2;
var i, j;
var infowindow;
var directionsDisplay;
var pointA, pointB;

    var locations = [
   <?php
            include('inc/config.php');
                $sql_lokasi="select *   from lokasi";
                $result=mysql_query($sql_lokasi) or die(mysql_error());
                while($data=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                     ?>
                        ['<?=$data->nama;?>', <?=$data->lat;?>, <?=$data->lng;?>],
       <?
                }
          ?>
    ];

    var locations2 = [
   <?php
            include('inc/config.php');
              $sql_lokasi="select idlokasi,nama,lat,lng,lat2,lng2 from lokasi";
              $result=mysql_query($sql_lokasi) or die(mysql_error());
              while($data=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                 ?>
                    ['<?=$data->nama;?>', <?=$data->lat2;?>, <?=$data->lng2;?>],
       <?
        }
    ?>
    ];

myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: pointA,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
},

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions),
ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
map: map
});

<?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lokasi");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        // foreach($result as $row) // <- remove this line
            echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat'].", ".$row['lng']."), map), 
          addMarker2(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat2'].", ".$row['lng2']."), map);";       
        ?>

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2])

  };

for (j = 0; j < locations2.length; j++) { 
      pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(locations2[j][1], locations2[j][2])

      };

    // get route from A to B
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(ser, ren, pointA, pointB);
}


function calculateAndDisplayRoute(ser, ren, pointA, pointB) {
ser.route({
origin: pointA,
destination: pointB,
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    ren.setDirections(response);
    } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }      
  });
}

function addMarker(pointA, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            map: map,
            icon: 'seru.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });

//show INFOWINDOW
        var contentString = 
        '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">START POINT</h3>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p>I want to show this with locations[i].lat and locations[1].lng</p>'+
        '<p>Web <a href="Facebook">'+
        'www.facebook.com</a> .</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

function addMarker2(pointB, map, j) {
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            map: map,
            icon: 'seru 2.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

//show INFOWINDOW
        var contentString = 
        '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">END POINT</h3>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p>I want to show this with locations[j].lat2 and locations[j].lng2</p>'+
        '<p>Web <a href="Facebook">'+
        'www.facebook.com</a> .</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker2);
        });
```

---

This is code for show both marker from database :

```
<?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lokasi (idlokasi,nama,lat,lng,lat2,lng2");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        // foreach($result as $row) // <- remove this line
            echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat'].", ".$row['lng']."), map), 
          addMarker2(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat2'].", ".$row['lng2']."), map);";
var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat'].", ".$row['lng'].")
var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat2'].", ".$row['lng2'].")
        ?>
```

[This is screenshot of my maps, there still one route direction on my map, i want to show direction from all that marker (marker yellow to marker red become one route direction)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdzSR.png)

[This is my database has contain id, name, and each lat lng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5yJn.png)

Comment: What problem are you having adding additional routes? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: A google.maps.LatLng object does not have a 'click' event.

Comment: i have added more code, my problem is how to show route direction from all marker i have? because i only show 1 route direction from 1 data marker.

Comment: what do you mean by "A google.maps.LatLng object does not have a 'click' event" ? i must delete it or what?

Comment: There aren't _any_ markers defined by the posted code, and the posted code adds 'click' listeners to google.maps.LatLng objects (pointA, pointB) which won't do anything useful.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: `google.maps.Marker` objects support click events; `google.maps.LatLng` objects don't.

Comment: if i remove the function of "click" in pointA & pointB, maps won't load. And how code should i put in marker with function "click" ?

Comment: My function on marker has already shown on php :

echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat'].", ".$row['lng']."), map), 
          addMarker2(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['lat2'].", ".$row['lng2']."), map);";

That's show marker I make and save it on database. And I called it from function :
----function addMarker(pointA, map)----

Comment: Lines 3 & 12 of the posted code don't make sense to me, why is that click event listener there?

Comment: i want to show infowindow from there, now i've deleted it and it works! but where i get my data from database to infowindow?

My maps show again but still don't solve my problem, to show direction from all data marker from my database to my maps

Comment: still get 1 route direction http://i.stack.imgur.com/VdzSR.png

Comment: What does "direction from all data marker from my database to my maps" mean? You want directions from each marker to all the other markers? Pictures aren't helpful, a [ Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be.  At least update the posted code with your latest version which removes the extraneous click listeners.

Comment: related question: [Array to create multiple routes on Google Maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778201/array-to-create-multiple-routes-on-google-maps-v3)

Comment: I mean I have database contain first lat lng for my first marker (a.k.a pointA) and second lat2 lng2 for my second marker (a.k.a pointB). I have show each marker to my maps, now i want to show route direction (marker to marker2) from all marker i've shown to maps. I have updated my code above

Comment: i've modified that question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778201/array-to-create-multiple-routes-on-google-maps-v3) to my own here, but still got problem

Comment: this is my database http://i.stack.imgur.com/J5yJn.png

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code that would display a route.

Comment: the function calculateAndDisplayRoute is display a route, but just one route

Comment: The posted code doesn't call it at all.

Comment: do you mean that function show display route direction only show 1 route on maps?

Comment: When I looked at the code you posted in the question, that function isn't being called.  Where/how are you expecting it to be run?

Comment: ups i'm sorry i forgot to add "calculateAndDisplayRoute(ser, ren, pointA, pointB);" under for loop locations. Thats for show directions

Comment: Your currently only calling that function once at the end of the `initMap` function. It only creates one route, so calling it once results in one route on your map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more than one route displayed by your `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function, you need to create a new `DirectionsRenderer` object for each route.  Note that the DirectionsService is subject to a quota and a rate limit, so at some point you will start to get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` responses from the `DirectionsService`.

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(ser, ren, pointA, pointB) {
  var ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  ser.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      ren.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
// DIRECTION
function initMap() {
  var marker, marker2;
  var i, j;
  var directionsDisplay;
  var pointA, pointB;
  pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]);
  myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: pointA,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions),
    ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    });

  // get routes from A to B
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2])
    var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(locations2[i][1], locations2[i][2])
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(ser, ren, pointA, pointB);
  }
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(ser, ren, pointA, pointB) {
  var ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  ser.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      ren.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
// New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)
// Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
// Morristown, NJ, USA (40.79676670000001, -74.4815438)
var locations = [
  ["New York, NY, USA", 40.7127837, -74.00594130],
  ["Newark, NJ, USA", 40.735657, -74.1723667],
  ["Morristown, NJ, USA", 40.7967667, -74.4815438]
];
// Baltimore, MD, USA (39.2903848, -76.61218930000001)
// Boston, MA, USA (42.3600825, -71.05888010000001)
// Rochester, NY, USA (43.16103, -77.6109219)
var locations2 = [
  ["Baltimore, MD, USA", 39.2903848, -76.6121893],
  ["Boston, MA, USA", 42.3600825, -71.0588801],
  ["Rochester, NY, USA", 43.16103, -77.6109219]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```