# Google Maps Directions API set multiple route not interconnected with each others

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-directions-api

I want to use Google Maps Directions API to display route on my website.

Can we set multiple route in google map?

For e.g. 
1) Route : A => B => C

2) Route X => Y

3) Route P => Q => R => S

Note : All routes path are not interconnected with each others

[image]

Comment: Yes you can.  Possible duplicate of [Array to create multiple routes on Google Maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778201/array-to-create-multiple-routes-on-google-maps-v3)

Comment: @Mit Makwana, have you found solution please help me by posting it